# importScripts in Web Workers is undefined inside a React/Webpack environment

Tags: reactjs, webpack, web-worker, create-react-app

I am working on a React app created with create-react-app. I was having trouble creating a web worker in it so I posted a question here on SO: [Creating a web worker inside React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47475360/creating-a-web-worker-inside-react)

I've found a solution, as written in the post above, to load a worker without ejecting the app and messing with the Webpack config. This is the code, from the post above:

```
// worker.js
const workercode = () => {

    self.onmessage = function(e) {
        console.log('Message received from main script');
        const workerResult = 'Received from main: ' + (e.data);
        console.log('Posting message back to main script');
        self.postMessage(workerResult);
    }
};

let code = workercode.toString();
code = code.substring(code.indexOf("{")+1, code.lastIndexOf("}"));

const blob = new Blob([code], {type: "application/javascript"});
const worker_script = URL.createObjectURL(blob);

module.exports = worker_script;
```

and in the file that uses the worker:

```
import worker_script from './worker';
const myWorker = new Worker(worker_script);

myWorker.onmessage = (m) => {
    console.log("msg from worker: ", m.data);
};
myWorker.postMessage('im from main');
```

It works, however, I cannot seem to get importScripts to work. Even if I do this (outside onmessage or inside onmessage):

```
if (typeof importScripts === 'function') {
    importScripts('myscript.js');
}
```

In that case, the if statement turns out to be true, but then fails on the actual import with the same error message `'importScripts' is not defined` as if the if statement is a false positive, which doesn't sound right. I'd say this is a context issue and that the worker probably isn't loading properly (although it seems to work), but it's just a guess.

Any ideas what's happening here?

Comment: Ever figure this out? I'm looking to do the same.

Comment: @esilac I ended up ejecting my create react app project and using worker-loader package to load my workers. I haven't tried using importScripts since, though. All my worker code is in the file loaded in the main script.

Answer (score 0):

`importScripts` in a worker created from Blob works fine, at least in 2021 (react 17.0.2, react-scripts 4.0.3, Chrome 92). The imported script URL must be absolute because worker was created from Blob.

The original issue might have been a bug in webpack or the transpilation might have changed the code in a weird way.

```
const workercode = () => {
    importScripts("https://example.com/extra.js");
    console.log(self.extraValue); // 10

    self.onmessage = function(e) {
        console.log('Message received from main script');
        ...
    }
};
```

```
// extra.js
self.extraValue = 10;
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this is still broken in 2022 - Seems there is a regression coming down the dev pipeline (at least in Android WebView and possibly some dev/canary chrome verions.)

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1078821