# webworkers don't seem to be working in production

Tags: javascript, web, browser, web-worker

I have an app and it uses webworkers to help do some computation with other workers. The error it throws is essentially complaining that the data it's expecting isn't there since the computations weren't computed.

The computations are performed locally with the webworkers running, but in prod I am pretty much out of ideas why it's not working.

One thing to note is that because I need the context of certain functions (defined outside of the worker context) imported in, I've followed the advice suggested here: ( [Creating a web worker inside React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47475360/creating-a-web-worker-inside-react) ) and am stringing it in first and turning it into a blob first.

`

```
export const buildBlobUrlFromCode = (code) => {
    // returns a DOMString that links context to the code within the blob
    code = code.substring(code.indexOf("{") + 1, code.lastIndexOf("}"));
    const blob = new Blob([code], { type: "application/javascript" });

    return URL.createObjectURL(blob);
}

export class WebWorker {
    constructor(worker) {
        let code = worker.toString();
        // const blobUrl = strDecoratedBuildBlobUrlFromCode(code);
        const blobUrl = buildBlobUrlFromCode(code);

        return new Worker(blobUrl);
    }
}
```

and how I use the above code is: 
`const workerInstance = new WebWorker(MyWorker);`

where `MyWorker` is a fn exported with `onmessage` defined and all the operations defined inside.

I added some logs, and essentially the code break when I start to kick the computation off with: `workerInstance.postMessage([data]);`

Also to note is that I'm using the react-create-app to build my app and I haven't ejected yet so the webpack configs are untouched.

Also -- the source files for these workers are completely blank when deployed, but are filled on local ( as in I can see the actual code in the worker.js files )

Heroku -- Broken: 
[image: On heroku (broken) -- deployed]

Local -- Working:
[image: On local (working) --]

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the exact same issue while creating web workers that way. Instead of creating the blob, this method worked for me:

App.js

```
const myWorker = new Worker(/* webpackChunkName: "myWorker" */ new URL('./myWorker.js', import.meta.url))
```

myWorker.js

```
self.onmessage = (event) => {}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with explanation as to why this solves the issue, and including relevant links to documentation

Answer (score 0):

We have been struggling with a similar issue and we found the following...

We are also using Webpack and importantly a production configuration which uglified the code. During this process we found that the onmessage function variable was being discarded as it was not being called anywhere else. This explained why no code was visible in the production build worker instance.

We also found another potential pitfall in that the uglification process was changing all variable names to single characters. This process would also render the onmessage function useless.

To fix it, instead of declaring the variable onmessage, assign onmessage to the global object (`this`)

`this.onmessage = (event) => {}`

This way the uglification did not discard the code and the function name was not altered.

I know this is late but hope it helps.