# Get reference for webWorker that has already been registered

Tags: javascript, web-worker

I have a web worker that i create like so in my parent component:-

```
if (window.Worker) {
  const worker = new Worker('myworker.js')
  this.setState({
    myWorkerRef: worker,
  })
}
```

Inside my component i can easily use the worker by calling:-

```
this.state.wishlistWorkerRef.postMessage({
    payload: { ...data },
})
```

But what if i want to use the same registered worker in another component without having to pass the reference in redux or state props ? How can i get a reference for an existing worker that is registered for a domain(same tab of-course) ?

Comment: You may want to add some more tag(s), based on `this.setState()`. Remembering an object is definitely not a problem in "pure" JS code.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Creating a web worker inside React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47475360/creating-a-web-worker-inside-react)